# How can I connect to Memgraph Cloud from Python

Tags: memgraphdb

I have Memgraph Lab installed on my computer as well as `mgconsole`. I know how to connect to Memgraph Cloud using them, but I'd like to connect to them using Python. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will to install a Python driver. You will actually [use GQLAlchemy](https://memgraph.com/docs/gqlalchemy/how-to-guides).

You can use pip (`pip install gqlalchemy`) or poetry (`poetry add gqlalchemy`).

In the following code, replace `YOUR_MEMGRAPH_PASSWORD`, `YOUR_MEMGRAPH_USERNAME` and `MEMGRAPH_HOST_ADDRESS` with your values:

```
from gqlalchemy import Memgraph

MEMGRAPH_HOST = 'MEMGRAPH_HOST_ADDRESS'
MEMGRAPH_PORT = 7687
MEMGRAPH_USERNAME = 'YOUR_MEMGRAPH_USERNAME'
# Place your Memgraph password that was created during Project creation
MEMGRAPH_PASSWORD = 'YOUR_MEMGRAPH_PASSWORD'

def hello_memgraph(host: str, port: int, username: str, password: str):
    connection = Memgraph(host, port, username, password, encrypted=True)
    results = connection.execute_and_fetch(
        'CREATE (n:FirstNode { message: "Hello Memgraph from Python!" }) RETURN n.message AS message'
    )
    print("Created node with message:", next(results)["message"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello_memgraph(MEMGRAPH_HOST, MEMGRAPH_PORT, MEMGRAPH_USERNAME, MEMGRAPH_PASSWORD)
```